# VBA Runtime Error 91

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make some calculation to validate data in a cell by compare the value with average from its row and place the validation result in another table.

When I run my code, i got:

> Run Time Error '91' : Object Variable or With Block not Set

I don't know what I'm missing. So, here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton17_Click()
Dim SelectedCheckCell As Range, LastValue As Range, ValidationValue As Range, LastValidatedCell As Long
Dim Average As Integer, SelectedRow As Integer, LastValidation As Integer
Dim result As String, result2 As String, SelectedCol As String

Set SelectedCheckCell = Application.InputBox("Select initial cell to validate:", xTitleId, Selection.Address, Type:=8)
Set LastValue = Application.InputBox("Select last cell to calculate:", xTitleId, Selection.Address, Type:=8)
Set ValidationValue = Application.InputBox("Select initial cell to place result of validate:", xTitleId, Selection.Address, Type:=8)

SelectedRow = Split(SelectedCheckCell.Address, "$")(2)
SelectedCol = Split(LastValue.Address, "$")(1)

LastValidatedCell = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
LastValidation = Split(LastValidatedCell.Address, "$")(2)

result = "OK"
result2 = "NOT OK"

For i = SelectedRow To LastValidation

    Average = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("C" & i & ":" & SelectedCol & i))

    If ((SelectedCheckCell.value < (Average - (Average * 0.1))) Or (SelectedCheckCell.value > (Average + (Average * 0.1)))) Then 
        ValidationValue.value = result
    Else
        ValidationValue.value = result2

End If

SelectedCheckCell = SelectedCheckCell.Offset(1, 0)
ValidationValue = ValidationValue.Offset(1, 0)

Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't **Average** be a double type var? It has been my experience that an average of many numbers very rarely resolves to an even integer.

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
SelectedCheckCell.Address
```

To

```
Selection.Address
```

Not sure what you are trying to do with this variables (LastValue.Address & ValidationValue.Address) since they don't consist and range objects when it is called without setting any object on it.

Comment: Down Voter should post comment to justify their action.  Otherwise downvoting is considered as blind action.